# R - apply function on each element of array in parallel

Tags: arrays, r, parallel-processing, multicore

I have measurements of maximum and minimum temperature and precipitation that are organized as arrays of size
(100x96x50769), where i and j are grid cells with coordinates associated and z means the number of measurements over time.

Conceptually, it looks like this:

[image]

I am using the `climdex.pcic` package to calculate indices of extreme weather events. Given a time series of maximum and minimum temperature and precipitation, the `climdexInput.raw` function will return a `climdexIput` object that can be used to determine several indices: number of frost days, number of summer days, consecutive dry days etc.

The call for the function is pretty simple:

```
ci <- climdexInput.raw(tmax=x, tmin=y, prec=z,
                       t, t, t, base.range=c(1961,1990))
```

where x is a vector of maximum temperatures, y is a vector of minimum temperatures, z is a vector of precipitation and t is a vector with dates under which x, y and z were measured.

What I would like to do is to extract the timeseries for each element of my array (i.e. each grid cell in the figure above) and use it to run the `climdexInput.raw` function.

Because of the large number of elements of real data, I want to run this task in parallel on my 4-core Linux server. However, I have no experience with parallelization in R.

Here's one example of my program (with intentionally reduced dimensions to make execution faster on your computer):

```
library(climdex.pcic)

# Create some dates
t <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2010-12-31'), 'day')

# Parse the dates into PCICt
t <- as.PCICt(strftime(t), cal='gregorian')

# Create some dummy weather data, with dimensions `# of lat`, `# of lon` and `# of timesteps`
nc.min <- array(runif(10*9*4018, min=0, max=15), c(10, 9, 4018))
nc.max <- array(runif(10*9*4018, min=25, max=40), c(10, 9, 4018))
nc.prc <- array(runif(10*9*4018, min=0, max=25), c(10, 9, 4018))

# Create "ci" object
ci <- climdexInput.raw(tmax=nc.max[1,1,], tmin=nc.min[1,1,], prec=nc.prc[1,1,],
                       t, t, t, base.range=c(2000,2005))

# Once you have “ci”, you can compute any of the indices provided by the climdex.pcic package.
# The example below is for cumulative # of dry days per year:
cdd <- climdex.cdd(ci, spells.can.span.years = TRUE)
```

Now, please note that in the example above I used only the first element of my array ([1,1,]) as an example in the `climdexInput.raw` function.

How can do the same for all elements taking advantage of parallel processing, possibly by looping over the dimensions `i` and `j` of my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach to do that:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(3))
res <- foreach(j = seq_len(ncol(nc.min))) %:% 
  foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(nc.min))) %dopar% {
    ci <- climdex.pcic::climdexInput.raw(
      tmax=nc.max[i,j,], 
      tmin=nc.min[i,j,],
      prec=nc.prc[i,j,],
      t, t, t, 
      base.range=c(2000,2005)
    )
  }
stopCluster(cl)
```

See my guide on parallelism using foreach: https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/.

Then, to compute an index, just use `climdex.cdd(res[[1]][[1]], spells.can.span.years = TRUE)` (`j` first, `i` second).

Comment: Thanks, your answer works! Just a couple of clarifications though: where should I put the `climdex.cdd` calculation: within the foreach loop or should I create a new loop for it? What if I want to calculate three more indices besides `climdex.cdd`, how should I store the resulting variables inside the loop? Sorry for these questions, but again I don't have much experience with multicore processing in R!

Comment: I think you should make new loops if new computations are faster.

Comment: Ok thanks. One last thing I noticed when processing my actual data: the object `res` gets huge in size (around 7 GB), and therefore my server's 32 GB RAM are completely exhausted with this computation, making it really slow. The processing never ends. Is there any way to write `res` to disk instead of keeping it in the memory during the loop?

Comment: You can always store part (e.g. each `j`) as rds files and then load them when you want to compute statistics in parallel (over `j`).